# Select checkbox based on value with Angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

How do i check checkbox which has value of for example 5 with angularjs.

I am getting JSON with all values of checkbox that needs to be checked , but i cant find anywhere how to automaticaly check checkbox with value of , with angular js.

Comment: Example or something would be helpful.

Comment: can you please share your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ngChecked](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChecked) directive for checking and unchecking a checkbox

Also if you want for example to set a checkbox to checked when the value is 5:

```
<input type="checkbox"  ng-model="checkbox_model" ng-checked="data.value=='5'"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" />
```

CONTROLLER

```
$scope.checkAll = function () {
    if (!$scope.selectedAll) {
        $scope.selectedAll = true;
    } else {
        $scope.selectedAll = false;
    }
}
```

Add this code to your controller and HTML this will definately help you